# Drag and Drop sequence order

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

may be the title of the question is not adequate, here is my problem, i'll start with giving you an example :

Original Sequence : 
0. Item_105
1. Item_13
2. Item_6
3. Item_14
4. Item_106

Modified Sequence : 
0. Item_105
1. Item_14
2. Item_13
3. Item_6
4. Item_106

Here i must have 2 indexes : 
Index1 = 3
Index2 = 1
which means that the old element 3 went to the new position 1

i'm actually working with C# language and when i drag an item to drop it in a new position sometime it gives me good indexes, sometimes not!!
this is the "for" loop i used to get the indexes :

```
for (int i = 0; i < stops.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (originalOrder[i] != modifiedOrder[i])
    {
        if (originalOrder[i] == modifiedOrder[i + 1] && index2 == -1)
            index2 = i;
        else if (modifiedOrder[i] == originalOrder[i + 1] && index2 == -1)
            index2 = i;
        if (originalOrder[i] != modifiedOrder[i + 1] && index1 == -1)
            index1 = i;
    }
}
```

So this is my problem : How to get the right indexes 1 and 2 ? I need the to do some staff later in the code, if i have the right indexes all the rest is OK!!

please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, the assymetry in your code looks suspicious.  Without looking very much at your current code, I would assume that it might be giving you the right answer when you drag an item in one direction but not the other.

```
index1 = -1;
index2 = stops.Count;  // This could be off by one
for (int i = 0; i < stops.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // First, find the bounds of what was moved
    if (originalOrder[i] != modifiedOrder[i] && index1 == -1)
    {
        index1 = i;
    }
    if (index1 != -1 && originalOrder[i] == modifiedOrder[i])
    {
        index2 = i-1;
        // No need to look at any more items
        break;
    }
}
// Swap indices depending on which direction item was moved
if (originalOrder[index1] != modifiedOrder[index2])
{
    int temp = index1;
    index1 = index2;
    index2 = temp;
}
```

I can't tell from your example what stops.Count represents.  You'll need to ensure that index 2 is initialized to the last index.